# How can I pass an Button ID to other Activity? Android

Tags: android, button

I have 2 activities, my first activity have 3 buttons with different IDs, how can I pass to the second activity the ID from the button that was clicked?

**
I have 3 different types of search, the second activity its a map, if click on button one will show X results, if click on button 2 will show Y results and if click on Buttom 3 will show N results, I was thinking to make the IF on map with the button ID, so Ill be able to check with one the user clicked**

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Maybe we can suggest an alternative?

Comment: Your next question is going to be how you can use the button from your first activity in the second one, and the answer is that you cannot, at least not directly. Whatever you are trying to do, you are going about it the wrong way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass it like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("intVariableName", v.getId()); //where v is button that is cliked, you will find it as a parameter to onClick method
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Retrieve it like this

```
Intent mIntent = getIntent();
int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("intVariableName", 0);
if(intValue == 0)
    // error handling (Will come in this if when button id is invalid)
else
{
   if(intValue == R.id.button1)
       // Do work related to button 1

   if(intValue == R.id.button2)
       // Do work related to button 2

   if(intValue == R.id.button3)
       // Do work related to button 3
}
```

Comment: Hi Rohit5k2, thank you for your  answer, I have a doubt, you are using a boolean value ok? True or False. how would I compare with the other 2 buttons to see which one was clicked? 

For example I have 3 ids... id1, id2 and id3. if the user click on button with id1 it will show X results on map for me, if he click on button with id2 it will show other resuls... how could I compare this? Sorry Im not an experient android programmer

Comment: I am not using a boolean. Please see my edited code.

Comment: =) thank you very much Rohit5k2! Your answer helped me a lot! =) I'll implement here in my code

Answer (score 1):

Use `getId()` on button click which returns an int. You can save it in `SharedPreferences` or send it through `Bundle`.

Comment: Bundle will be much better

Comment: It depends on how and when you want to use the id.

Comment: As per question its simple passing to another activity. Bundle is the solution here.

Answer (score 1):

Do it through `Intent`

```
Button myButton = <GetYourButton>;
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("FirstButtonID", myButton.getId());
startActivity(intent);
```

Retrieve in the second `Activity` inside `onCreate`:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
int buttonId = intent.getIntExtra("FirstButtonID", <DefaultButtonIDIncaseNoneIsPassed>);
```